# exporting whole page to pdf with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

i need to export a pages to pdf, the pages will have grids on as they are reports.
i have had a look at iTextSharp which for exporting JUST the grid works a treat. But when i try it with the whole page, it gets a bit confused with the images in the page, and doesnt deal with the styling particularly well.. 
is it possible to export a whole page in one hit, or do i have to add in page elements on a per element basis?

thanks

nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add and format the elements ... remember, html != pdf ... so you will have to provide that translation